# DomPDF no imprime lo mismo que muestra

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

aclarando el título de esta pregunta:

Resulta que DomPDF tiene dos botones, descargar e imprimir; al descargar aparece el archivo tal como lo muestra en la vista previa, pero al imprimir simplemente desaparecen algunos márgenes en la parte de abajo de las páginas e incluso hay texto que se oculta.
No me imaginé que fuera diferente el imprimir directamente que descargar.
Alguna sugerencia?
Aquí dejo el código por si es de utilidad

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    @page { margin-top: ' . $top . ';'
        . 'margin-right: ' . $right . ';'
        . 'margin-bottom: ' . $bottom . ';'
        . 'margin-left: ' . $left . ';}
    body{font-size: 10px;color: black;font-family: arial;}
    #header { position: fixed; top: -15mm; height: 20mm; text-align: center; }
    #footer { position: fixed; right: 0px;left: 0px; bottom: -25mm; height:20mm; text-align: center;}
    #contador:after { content: counter(page); }
    #watermark { position: absolute;top: -75px;left: -55px;width: 120%;text-align: center;z-index: -1000;}
    p {margin: 0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
' . $divMarcaAgua . '
' . $header . '
' . $footer . '
<div ' . $styleLetra . ' id="content">
' . $_CUERPO . '
</div>
</body>
</html>';
// Render the HTML as PDF
if (!empty($_REQUEST["pdfGuard"])) {
    if ($_REQUEST["pdfGuard"] == "pdf") {
        $pdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
        $pdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Helvetica');
        $pdf->set_paper("folio", "portrait");
        $pdf->loadHtml($html);
        $pdf->render();
        $dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . _BASE_PATH . "media/";
        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777);
        }
        $dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . _BASE_PATH . "media/pdf/";
        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777);
        }
        $pdfs = $pdf->output();
        file_put_contents($dir . '/documento' . date('Y-m-d') . '.pdf', $pdfs);
    } else if ($_REQUEST["pdfGuard"] == "html") {
        echo $_CUERPO;
    }
} else {
//    Close and output PDF document   
    $pdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
    $pdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Helvetica');
    $pdf->set_paper("folio", "portrait");
    $pdf->loadHtml($html);
    $pdf->render();
    $f;
    $l;
    if (headers_sent($f, $l)) {
        echo $f, '<br/>', $l, '<br/>';
        die('now detect line');
    }
    $pdf->stream($contrato["nombre"] . " " . $NOMBRE_INMUEBLE . date("YmdHis") . ".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
}
```

Al imprimir: [image: Boton imprimir]

[image: Esto al imprimir]

Al descargar: [image: Boton descargar]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PDT: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Has de tener en cuenta que el css dentro de `@page` solo se interpreta para la impresion, es posible que los margenes indicados sean los que alteran el resultado.

Comment: Hola, @Xerif te agradezco tú respuesta; entonces trato de insertar css en [@]page y no parece funcionar
Si sabes, ¿cómo podría darle márgenes a las páginas de impresión para que estas no corten los párrafos a la mitad?

Comment: Puedes revisar la lista de CSS compatible con `Dompdf`  aquí: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility